# ListFragmentの各リストの動的な変更について

Tags: android, android-listfragment

お世話になっております。

現在ListFragmentを使用し、アプリを作っているのですが、
ListFragmentの各リストをタップするとダイアログを出し、ダイアログの値をそのリストに入れたいのですが、
動的に変更する方法がいまいち思いつきません。

どなたかいい方法をご存知の方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 何らかのListAdapterでリストのデータを設定していると思いますが、どのように設定していますか? 何らかのコードを共有していただけると答えやすいです

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ダイアログは DialogFragment を使うという前提とすると、Fragment 間でどのように結果を受け渡すかというのが問題になります。

ポイントは以下の通りです。

1. 通知を受け取りたいフラグメントは、対象のフラグメントに対して `setTargetFragment()` を呼んで呼び出し元を知らせる。
2. 通知を送るフラグメントは、`getTargetFragment()` と `getTargetRequestCode()` を使い、 `onActivityResult()` で通知する。
3. 通知を受け取ったら、ArrayAdapter の中のデータを更新し、`notifyDataSetChanged()` で更新を反映する(ArrayAdapterの場合)。

以下の様な感じで書きます。上記のポイントと関連する部分に日本語のコメントを入れておきました。

https://github.com/zaki50/DynamicListItemUpdateSample に、動作するアプリが作れるプロジェクトを置きました。

```
package com.example.dynamiclistitemupdate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new MyListFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public static class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

        private static final int REQ_DIALOG = 1;

        private int mItemIndex = -1;

        private String[] mItemData = {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-"};

        public MyListFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mItemData));
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

            mItemIndex = position - l.getHeaderViewsCount();

            DialogFragment newFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
            // ダイアログフラグメントに対して、結果の通知先を指定。結果は onActivityResult を呼び出すことで通知される
            newFragment.setTargetFragment(this, REQ_DIALOG);
            newFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode != REQ_DIALOG || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                return;
            }

            if (mItemIndex < 0 || data == null
                    || data.getStringExtra(MyDialogFragment.RESULT_EXTRA_KEY_TEXT) == null) {
                return;
            }

            // ArrayAdapter の中の配列を更新し、notifyDataSetChanged() で更新を通知する
            mItemData[mItemIndex] = data.getStringExtra(MyDialogFragment.RESULT_EXTRA_KEY_TEXT);
            final ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<?>) getListAdapter();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public static final String RESULT_EXTRA_KEY_TEXT = "text";

        public MyDialogFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("ダイアログ")
                    .setPositiveButton("はい", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, "yes");
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("いいえ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, "no");
                        }
                    });
            return builder.create();
        }

        /**
         * 結果をダイアログ表示元へ通知するためのメソッド。
         *
         * targetFragment に通知元がセットされているので、onActivityResult を呼び出すことで通知を行う。
         */
        private void sendResult(int resultCode, String str) {
            final Intent data = new Intent();

            if (str != null) {
                data.putExtra(RESULT_EXTRA_KEY_TEXT, str);
            }

            // 結果を通知する
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

別解として、event bus 系のライブラリを使うという方法もあります。いくつか有名所を上げておきます。

- [greenrobot EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)
- [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)
- [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained)

私は greenrobot EventBus を使うことが多いですが、 Otto もよく使われているようです。event bus についてはQiitaにも[エントリ](http://qiita.com/KeithYokoma/items/793aaac6994c9242808f)がありました。

Comment: 独自コールバック用のinterfaceを作るのが王道な気がしますが、最近はEventBusで手抜き(?)をすることが多いです。私もgreenrobot好きです。

Comment: Fragment が Activity に通知するときは callback用 interface を用意して onAttach() で参照を持っておく、呼び出し元のFragment に結果を通知するときは 今回の回答のように 呼び出し側で setTargetFragment() しておくというのが王道ですね。 EventBus は今回の件に限らずいろいろなシーンで使えるのでおさえておいて損はないですね

Comment: 大変返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
コードまで乗せていただいてありがとうございます。
EvantBusは初耳の技術です。毎度、独自コールバックInterfaceを
実装しておりましたので是非参考にさせていただきたいと思います。
Fragment間でデータのやりとり方法まで親切にありがとうございました。

Answer (score -1):

ダイアログから何かを変更するならカスタムダイアログを作って初期化時にインターフェースを渡します。

インターフェースの例

```
public interface setInterface{
    public void setter( input );
}
```

ダイアログの例

```
public static class TestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    setInterface target;

    //コンストラクタでinterfaceをセット
    TestDialogFragment( setInterface target ){
        this.target = target;
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("ダイアログ")
                .setPositiveButton("はい", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        target.setter( YES ); 書込み
                    }
                })            
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

setterの定義は、フラグメント自体に書いてしまうのが一番楽です。Listの各要素がデータクラスなりViewクラスなりを持っているならそちらに書きましょう。
例えばフラグメント自体に書くなら,

```
public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment implements setInterface {
     @Override
     public void setter( String input ){ 
         TextView title = this.targetView.findViewWithTag("title");
         title.setText(input); 
     };

     @Override
     public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
         this.targetView = l;//イベント元を保持
         DialogFragment newFragment = new TestDialogFragment(this);//インターフェースを渡す
         newFragment.show(mActivity.getFragmentManager(), "test");
     }
     //省略
}
```

Comment: Fragment を継承したクラスで引き数ありのコンストラクタを使う方法は、正しい方法ではありません。今回のように Fragment から Activity のメソッドを呼びたい場合は Fragment#onAttach(Activity) をオーバーライドし、そこでActivity なり コールバックオブジェクトの3章を保持するようにする必要があります。

引き数なしのコンストラクタがないとフレームワークがFragment を再生成するタイミングでエラーになるし、回答のコードに引数なしのコンストラクタを追加しただけでは、Fragment再生性が起こるとコールバックする際に NPEが発生してしまいます。

Comment: 確かにこの方法は画面回転などでDialogFragmentが再生成されると問題が起きますね。
今回はFragmentからFragmentのメソッドを呼びたいわけですが、ActivityにListFragment用のcallbackとDialog用のcallbackをそれぞれ用意して、onAttachで登録して呼ぶという形が正しいのでしょうか？

Comment: あ、今回はActivity を経由しない構成でしたね。コメントに書くにはちょっと複雑なので、別の回答の形で書きます。ポイントは、Fragment#setTarget(Fragment,int) メソッドです。